# Is there a way to list the groups of a user who is a contact of the authenticated user on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin-api

The [LinkedIn API documentation has confused me](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api#membergroups). It says that it is possible to list the groups of a user (not the logged in user, but any contact of the user) by providing the `person-id`.

The url shows this as an example:

```
To Get the Group of the Logged In User:
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/group-memberships:(group:(id,name,counts-by-category))?membership-state=member
```

I've tried the following

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/person-id=abcde/group-memberships:(group:(id,name,counts-by-category))?membership-state=member
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/abcde/group-memberships:(group:(id,name,counts-by-category))?membership-state=member
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/group-memberships:(group:(id,name,counts-by-category))?membership-state=member&person-id=abcde
```

None of them work. Where should I put the person-id? It's driving me bananas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the LinkedIn Groups API [doesn't support retrieval of groups for anybody else except the logged in user](https://developer.linkedin.com/forum/group-memberships).